# Task failing on project build (Could not resolve all files for configuration)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I've noticed that this is a common problem when building app. Everytime I try to build my project I get this error, but the build.gradle at all levels is the same as another project's which gets built without any problem. I've tried placing the repositories one above the other in many ways, but it just won't work. I also tried downloading from 2 different Internet connections as recommended in some forums, but no luck there. This is the error:

```
> Task :app:preDebugBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:^4.2.2.
  Required by:
      project :app
```

Please keep in my mind that the following specs are the same for the other project that is getting built perfectly.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.6.0 (C:\Users\joelf\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.11.1\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.8
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.12.2
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\joelf\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\)
   NodeJS            : v12.11.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.11.3
   OS                : Windows 10
```

And my gradle.build files are looking like these:

- `build.gradle` at app level: https://www.codepile.net/raw/4gq79YX7.groovy
- `build.gradle` at platforms/android level: https://www.codepile.net/raw/5qVDX28b.groovy
- `build.gradle` at CordovaLib level: https://www.codepile.net/raw/GRwprwZ1.groovy

If you need any other file just let me know, it's my first time working with gradle, ionic and cordova, so I'm kind of lost in here, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please add your build gradle app level

Comment: it's actually there listed with link to the full code, I mistyped it as 'gradle.build' instead of 'build.gradle' haha sorry about that, but I just edited and it's right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this :

```
 implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2"
```

instead of this :

```
 implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:^4.2.2"
```

edit :

You can add it like this

```
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.2.2'
```

and to get dependencies from maven you need to add this to your repositories

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Excuse my question, but where would you write this?

Comment: build.gradle app level

Comment: Even if I use it that way, it automatically changes to implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:^4.2.2" when I run the debug in my emulator. Any idea why?

Comment: I even change the okhttp version in package.json, but on my app level build.gradle still changes to ^4.2.2.

Comment: This is a strange behaviour ! Remove that line and clean your project and then write it again

Comment: I did clean with gradlew clean and deleted that implementation line from the build.gradle at app level, but still rewrites it automatically as ^4.2.2 :/

Comment: I ended up changing this on my package.json and everything worked fine. Just had to change it there so the change could refllect on my gradle file.